# Passing variable from python script to bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Currently trying to pass a parameter from my python script to a bash script I created. How can I can get user input from my python script to my bash script?

This is the code for my python script 'passingParameters.py' which I used to try and send a variable (loop) to my bash script. I have tested this python script (after I adjusted the code) by sending the output to another python script which I used to read the input.

```
loop = str(sys.argv[1])
subprocess.check_call( ["./test.sh", loop], shell=True)
```

This is the code for my bash script 'test.sh'. I have tested this script by itself to confirm that it does receive user input when I just call the bash script from the command line.

```
echo "This number was sent from the passParameters.py script: " $1﻿
```

Comment: Pretty related: [How do I pass a Python Variable to Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796932/how-do-i-pass-a-python-variable-to-bash)

Comment: The code should work. Do you get an error? Or why do you think the parameter isn't passed?

Comment: @AaronDigulla no error, just the value I input into the command line doesn't show up

Comment: @MOS182 See my comment to [crono's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25140918/1126841).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables from python script to bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4257098/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `shell=True` then the executable is `/bin/sh`, which then calls test.sh but never sees the `loop` variable. You can either set `shell=False` and add the `#!/bin/sh` to the shell script,

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "This number was sent from the passParameters.py script: " $1﻿
```

and

```
subprocess.check_call( ["./test.sh", loop], shell=False)
```

or pass the variable as a string:

```
subprocess.check_call( ["./test.sh %s" % loop], shell=True)
```

`shell=True` is not recommended anyway.

Comment: +1 It's not well documented, but combining your list of arguments with `shell=True` will result in the following command: `sh -c ./test.sh <loop>`. This will still run `./test.sh`, but the argument `loop` is passed to `sh` as `$0` rather than to `./test.sh` as `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This first suggestion works fine. I tried the second suggestion with shell=True and it didn't work, says invalid syntax for the % beside loop.

Comment: @chepner that's what I thought might have explained why it wasn't displayed so instead of having $1 in the bash script, I tried $0 and it still didn't print out anything.

Comment: When you pass the variable as a string, the list is just superfluous. `subprocess.check_call("./test.sh %s" % loop, shell=True)`. But as you note, you really want to avoid `shell=True` if you can. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)